# Enumerate the number of unordered strings

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Say I have a set $\{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}$ and want to make $m$-length products of these elements, commutatively, i.e. $e_1e_2e_1e_3e_4e_1=e_1^3e_2e_3e_4$. How many ways are there to do this?

Am I correct in thinking this is:
$$\left(\!\!\binom{n}{m}\!\!\right)?$$

Say I had $\{e_1,e_2\}$ and wanted to count the number of $4$-length monomials, then I have:
$$\left(\!\!\binom{2}{4}\!\!\right)= {5\choose 4}=5$$
$$\{e_1^4,e_1^3e_2,e_1^2e_2^2,e_1e_2^3,e_2^4\}$$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  As for typesetting the multichoose function however, I recommend `\left(\!\!\binom{n}{m}\!\!\right)` using more or less `\!`'s as necessary depending on font size.  The effect of `\!` is to decrease the horizontal space between characters.  For more information on the multichoose function, see [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and [multichoose](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multichoose.html).

Comment: @JMoravitz That does look nice, thanks!

Comment: As an additional aside, it may be worth avoiding the multichoose notation since both $\left(\!\binom{n}{m}\!\right)$ and $\left(\!\binom{m}{n}\!\right)$ are used where $n$ is the number of characters available and $m$ is the length of the string.  I remember confusing myself quite a bit when studying from Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics and he followed the opposite convention of what I was used to.  Binomial coefficients at least don't have an ambiguous meaning at this point, so I'd jump straight to the binomial coefficient result.

Comment: @JMoravitz Interesting, so avoid ambiguity by only considering ${{n+k-1}\choose {k}}$, that seems reasonable. Thanks for the heads up.